# Could you help me with that Vector subspace proof 2

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove that these S's are Linear subspaces of V.
[image]

Could you help me with that Vector subspace proof?

I tried:

1-If I choose any real number and to multiply by a negative value, can I say that 1) isn't a subspace of V?

2- In this case I think that I can represent all numbers. I'm not sure.

3- I was thinking about:
Be u = (x,y,z) and alfa = Any real number.

We have: alfa*(x,y,z) = (alfa*x, alfa*y, alfa*z), alfa*x>0, if alfa>0, but if alfa<0, we have a*x<0. So, it is not a subspace

4- if I get x= (2)^(1/2)? I think that it's false too.

Comment: You seem to have the right ideas for which are subspaces and which aren't.  Some thing's you've said aren't clear, though.  What do you mean by *"In this case I think that I can represent all numbers"*, and what does $x = \sqrt{2}$ have to do with 4?

Comment: 4)- √2 don't belong to Q, it's an irrational number. So, if I choose x=√2 and y=0, I can't represent x+y as belonging to this subspace.

Comment: 2- I can choose any scalar number who belongs to real numbers, so, if I to multiply p(x) by a negative scalar, I have a -p(x).

Comment: For 4: so, you've shown that $(\sqrt{2},0,z)$ is not an element of $S$.  But why does this mean that $S$ is not a vector subspace?  For 2: are you saying that this *is* a subspace, or that it *is not*?

Comment: for 4: Ok. the question is saying that only x+y = rational number is valid, and x+y can be irrational and rational, so if I get just the rational numbers, this is right, it is a subspace of V.

Comment: In fact, the space in 4 will not be a subspace of $V$. I'll clarify in an answer.

Comment: For 2: I'm saying now that this is not a subspace, because given u=(x1, y1) and v= (x2,y2), cos(u+x) is different of cos(u) +cos(v), for exemple.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:**

As you indicated, $S$ is not a subspace.  To show this, consider $p(x) = x^2$.  Note that $p(x) \in S$, but $-1 \cdot p(x) \notin S$.  So, $S$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.

**Question 2:**

This is, in fact, a subspace.  Show that it is closed under both scalar multiplication and addition.

**Question 3:**

Indeed, $S$ is not a subspace.  To show this, consider $(1,2,3) \in S$, and note that $-1 \cdot (1,2,3) = (-1,-2,-3) \notin S$.

**Question 4:**

Indeed, $S$ is not a subspace.  To show this, consider $(1,0,0) \in S$, and note that $\sqrt{2} \cdot (1,0,0) = (\sqrt{2},0,0) \notin S$.